# Changing a divs content depending on media size?

Tags: html, css, image, background, responsive

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up64F.png

[wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE6Ib.jpg)

Hi, I'm struggling with my website order css- basically I want a background image on both desktop and mobile version but depending on the different version depends on what is displayed ontop of the desktop image. Currently I have tried playing around with making a div for background and not adding any content to it and just trying to make the width etc. right depending on the screen parameters- however its not been great : wondering if theres a way of moving the content in and out of the div depending on screen size? or if there's any other better way of doing it? diagrams of the layout are on the image ive linked in
thanks!

Comment: Have you tried maybe multiple divs and displaying them based on media queries?

Comment: Yes, you can change divs content depending on media size for more details please check https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @Umesh by this do you mean I should put all attributes in both the div and out of div and then hide/show dependant on screen size?

Comment: @EdwinCruz am trying this at the moment- didn't want to repeat code though- but if its needed I'll continue with this!

Comment: If you show what type of "content" you are trying to change we might be able to help a little better.

Comment: Just added a second image of the wireframe - hope this helps this is the index page the large section on the left will always be main - its then translated as shown on the first diagram linked. Thanks

Comment: Yes OR you can can simply call class/id to current div's & show/hide dependent screen size by using css media queries.